# Converting character to number

Tags: r

```
levels(Auto$doornumber) <- c(4, 2)
Auto$doornumber <- as.numeric(levels(Auto$doornumber))[Auto$doornumber]
```

I am not sure why the code above is not converting my variable from character to numeric in my dataframe.

```
Auto <- doornumber = c(two, four, two, four)
```

I want the above variable/column has been changed to

```
Auto <- doornumber = c(2, 4, 2, 4)
```

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, at least not the right dupe. Maybe relevel, then as.numeric kind of duplicate.

Comment: Maybe try: `as.numeric(factor(Auto$doornumber, levels = c("one", "two", "three", "four")))`

Comment: Not sure if you know what `Auto <- doornumber = c(2, 4, 2, 4)` does.. It just assigns `c(2, 4, 2, 4)` to both `Auto` and `doornumber`. Not to `Auto$doornumber`.

Comment: @zx8754 Its not working. In my dataframe, variable doornumber contains only ("two, "four") which i need to convert like (2, 4).

Comment: @Axeman, what is the solution?

Comment: Then maybe try: `Auto$doornumber <- setNames(c(2, 4), c("two", "four"))[ Auto$doornumber ]`

Comment: Thank you @ZX it works perfectly